# Installing the 7-segment LCD font and using it for drop caps

Tags: fonts, drop-cap

I was reading on [TUG](https://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html) about installing a new font, and trying to apply this to the [Segment](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/segmentfont/) font, however the `capbas.zip` file which I downloaded from the linked page did not contain the directory structure expected by the write-up at TUG. How should I install this font?

The ultimate goal is to use this font in the drop caps. I previously used `Royal Initialen` as per [this answer](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/segmentfont/), but assume that `Segment` will have to be set up differently, as it is a custom macro. Can anyone please help to figure how to use a drop cap in Segment?

Comment: That is a bitmap  font. Are you sure you want to use it?

Comment: Not entirely sure yet, because I did not see it in action, but at least I want to try.

Comment: For a test you can simply throw everything in your test folder.

Comment: It worked, and you were right - the font is butt-ugly. Yuck! Is there a real scalable LCD font?

Comment: for an active maintained ttf (and woff) see https://github.com/keshikan/DSEG for older (stagnant) OTF versions see several  https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/segment14 or https://github.com/ctrlcctrlv/lcd-font and https://www.1001fonts.com/lcd-font.htm and what about 16 segs however only available as transparent png sheets at https://github.com/dmadison/LED-Segment-ASCII so you would need to auto clip into characters (too messy for \includes ?) or as ttf at https://fonts2u.com/led-16-segment.font